# Why is a tarball called tarball and not just tar?

Tags: tar

This may sound like a strange question, but I really wonder why we use this word. There must be a good reason.

Comment: http://www.eps.mcgill.ca/jargon/jargon.html#tarball

Comment: Answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225000/where-the-term-tarball-comes-from

Answer (score 1):

A "tarball" is not just a tar archive.  It's a tar archive that's been compressed (typically gzipped).  So calling it a "tar" wouldn't be accurate, and calling it a "tar dot gz" doesn't sound as cool.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. It just says that "tar dot gz" isn't as cool as "tarball" without saying *why* the word "tarball" came about.

Comment: @ColeTobin: The question is why it's a tarball *and not just tar*.